# Python xmpppy client not sending message to appengine xmpp client

Tags: python, google-app-engine, xmpp, xmpppy

Hey Guys,
I seem to be having trouble using the xmpppy client when sending messages to the app engine's xmpp client. 
I am not getting any errors. The messages just aren't arriving there. 
Sending messages from app engine's client to the sl4a client works. 
Sending messages to and from google talk's client to and from the sl4a client works as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the python code

```
import xmpp
import time

_SERVER = 'talk.google.com', 5223
commandByXMPP()

def commandByXMPP():
  global xmppUsername
  xmppUsername = 'garrowsbot@gmail.com'  
  global xmppPassword
  xmppPassword = 'obscured'  
  global xmppClient
  global operator
  operator = "cellbotmote@appspot.com"

  jid = xmpp.protocol.JID(xmppUsername)
  xmppClient = xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(), debug=[])
  xmppClient.connect(server=_SERVER)
  try:
    xmppClient.RegisterHandler('message', XMPP_message_cb)
  except:
    exitCellbot('XMPP error. You sure the phone has an internet connection?')
  if not xmppClient:
    exitCellbot('XMPP Connection failed!')
    return
  auth = xmppClient.auth(jid.getNode(), xmppPassword, 'botty')
  if not auth:
    exitCellbot('XMPP Authentication failed!')
    return
  xmppClient.sendInitPresence()
  print "XMPP username for the robot is:\n" + xmppUsername

  start=time.time()
  i=0
  try:
    outputToOperator("starting")
    while time.time()-start<15:
      print "tick"
      xmppClient.Process(1)
      i = i +1
      if i % 10 == 0:
        outputToOperator("hello")
    outputToOperator("exiting")
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass


def XMPP_message_cb(session, message):
  jid = xmpp.protocol.JID(message.getFrom())
  global operator
  command = message.getBody()
  print command

def outputToOperator(msg):
  print "Outputting "+msg+" to " + operator
  xmppClient.send(xmpp.Message(operator, msg))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Check that garrowsbot@gmail.com is on the roster for cellbotmote@appspot.com.  GTalk won't deliver messages from unknown users.
2) Send a message of type chat:

```
xmppClient.send(xmpp.Message(operator, msg, typ='chat'))
```

Some clients do not react well to receiving "normal" messages, which don't have a `type` attribute.

Comment: Thank you Joe. Ive been trying to hunt this down for about a week. Many thanks to you good sir.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. I had to specify the type. Although he is right, you will need to make sure they are on each other's rosters.