# XMPP on Python responds to Gtalk but not to Hangouts

Tags: python, xmpppy

I was trying out a Gtalk bot using python and XMPP.

When I ping the bot using iChat application, I could receive the response back.
But when I ping using Hangouts, I am not able to receive the response message. But still I could see my message at server side logs.

```
# -- coding: utf-8 -
import xmpp 

user="BOTUSERNAME@gmail.com"
password="PASSWORD"
server=('talk.google.com', 5223)

def message_handler(connect_object, message_node): 
        us = str(message_node.getFrom()).split('/')[0]
        if us == 'REALUSERNAME@gmail.com':
            us = us[0:4]
            print str(message_node)
            message = "Welcome to my first Gtalk Bot :) " + us
            s= str(message_node.getBody()).replace("\n", "\t")
            if s <> 'None' :
                print "MESSAGE: " + s
                connect_object.send(xmpp.Message( message_node.getFrom() ,message))

jid = xmpp.JID(user) 
connection = xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain()) 
connection.connect(server) 
result = connection.auth(jid.getNode(), password ) 

connection.RegisterHandler('message', message_handler)  
connection.sendInitPresence() 

while connection.Process(1): 
    pass
```

Is this something to do with gtalk moving out of XMPP support?

My Bot is still able to receive message but my Hangouts Application is not receiving response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue.

You need to add `typ = 'chat'` attribute to `xmpp.Message`

```
connect_object.send(xmpp.Message( message_node.getFrom() ,message, typ='chat' ))
```

Now my gTalkBot reponds to my message from hangouts & ichat client.

Many thanks to this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4620346/3313914!)

Answer (score 0):

If you have extended `sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP`, then you can ensure messages are sent to hangouts by added `mtype='chat'` to `send_message()`

```
bot = MyBot([...])
bot.send_message(mto=JID,mbody=MSG,mtype='chat')
```